# Flex textInput custom border color

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

How can I change the textinput field border color to white?

Example code:

```
 <s:TextInput id="mytxt" width="100%" maxChars="40" textAlign="center" restrict="A-Z a-z 0-9"/>
```

Thank you.

Comment: May be this is relevant: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/459757

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and fastest way would be to add the borderColor property:

```
<s:TextInput borderColor="0xffffff"/>
```

Keep in mind instead of a #(hash) based colour (#ffffff) you need to pass the variable in as uint instead of string. So for #ffffff you instead use 0xffffff.

Comment: the `borderColor` property does not seem to exist on my `s:TextInput` control? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Create a spark TextInput

```
<s:TextInput id="txt2" styleName="textStyle" />
```

Add style by using

```
<fx:Style source="style.css" />
```

In the style.css you have to add

```
.textStyle
{
  borderColor: #FFFFFF;
}
```